# Temporary value dropped while borrowed in rust program

Tags: rust

In module db.rs , while reading the value from the DataBase, i got the Error  **temporary value dropped while borrowed
consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value**

```
use bytes::Bytes;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Db {
    // pub entries: Arc<bool>,
    pub entries: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, Bytes>>>,
}
impl Db {
    pub fn new() -> Db {
        Db {
            entries: Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new())),
        }
    }
    /// Reads data from the database
    pub fn read(&mut self, arr: &[String]) -> Result<Bytes, &'static str> {
        let key = &arr[1];
        let query_result = self.entries.lock().unwrap().get(key);// Error in this Line.

        if let Some(value) = query_result {
            return Ok(Bytes::from("hello"));
        } else {
            return Err("no such key found");
        }
    }
}
```

but when i modify the code and trying to get the value in the next line, it didn't give any error.

```
let query_result = self.entries.lock().unwrap();
let result =  query_result.get(key);
```

can anyone help me understand what's going on under the hood?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73276159/edit) your question to add the full error message from `cargo check` (not from an IDE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see why Rust thinks this is an error by checking how `Mutex::lock` works. If successful, it doesn't return a reference directly, it returns a `MutexGuard` struct that can deref into the type it wraps, a `HashMap` in your case.

The signature of `Deref::deref<Target = T>` is (with the elided lifetimes added):

```
fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a T
```

This means that the `MutexGuard` can only give us a reference to the `HashMap` inside for as long as it is itself alive (the lifetime `'a`). But because you never store it anywhere, instead dereferencing it directly, Rust thinks that it gets dropped right after the call to `get`. But you keep the result of `get` around, which can only live for as long as the reference to the `HashMap` passed into it, which in turn only lives as long as the `MutexGuard` which gets dropped immediately.

If you store the `MutexGuard`, on the other hand, like

```
let guard = self.entries.lock().unwrap();
let query_result = guard.get(key);
```

it only gets dropped at the end of the scope, so any references it gave out are also valid until the end of the scope.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the `Deref` Part, i was totally missing it. When i was implementing insert and used ` self.entries.lock().unwrap().insert(String::from(key), Bytes::from(val));` it was not giving me any such errors when i was accessing the value. Probably because it returns `Option<Bytes>` however, in case of Get   it is returning `Option<&Bytes>` Additionally i had to clone the `&Bytes` to return from the function.

Comment: In case of insert, the function returns the **value** `Bytes`. Value was stored in the local variable with `let`. But in case of get, the function returned the reference to the data on the heap (&Bytes). In my case, since `MutexGuard`  was getting dropped as per your explanation in the answer, the reference was also getting dropped.

Comment: Yeah, you got it. By the way, it looks like your `read` method doesn't need to take `self` by mutable reference. A shared reference would suffice.